# Print function result after onClick action

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I'm a newbie so please excuse my very basic code, I'm trying to print the result of a life path calculation but it doesn't seem to detect the result that I want to get.

So I changed my code according to a sample given, here is the calculator() function in which I'm getting the value of FinalLifeNumber and passing it to switchVisible().

```
 document.getElementById("PathNumber").innerHTML = "Life Path Number: " + sumMonth + sumDays + FinalYear + " = " + FinalLifeNumber;

        switchVisible(FinalLifeNumber);
    }
```

I'm trying to pass it on to this next function switchVisible() that should output the div classes it equals to.

```
 function switchVisible(FinalLifeNumber) {

            var cal = FinalLifeNumber;

            document.getElementsByClassName('LP1')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP2')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP3')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP4')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP5')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP6')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP7')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP8')[0].style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName('LP9')[0].style.display = "none";

            switch (cal) {
                case 1: document.getElementsByClassName('LP1')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 2: document.getElementsByClassName('LP2')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 3: document.getElementsByClassName('LP3')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 4: document.getElementsByClassName('LP4')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 5: document.getElementsByClassName('LP5')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 6: document.getElementsByClassName('LP6')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 7: document.getElementsByClassName('LP7')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 8: document.getElementsByClassName('LP8')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
                case 9: document.getElementsByClassName('LP9')[0].style.display = "block"; break;
            }
        }
```

This is the sample div class.

```
  <div class="LP1">
                <p id="LifePlan1">
                    <h1 style="background-color:brown;"><b> The Natural Born Leader </b></h1>
                    The Life Path 1 is one of leadership and trailblazing. With a strong sense of independence, you do not like relying on other people, especially if you feel they are holding you back. Often, you may feel like it is better to go it alone.
                    <br />
                    You would do well as an entrepreneur because you aren't afraid to take risks! You march to the beat of your own tune and the people around you generally don't hear until the tune is completed and on the top 100 charts. You tend to do things your own way and create innovation by stirring up the pot. People such as Henry Ford, Charlie Chaplin, Ozzy Osbourne, Tom Cruise, all stayed true to their Life Path 1, you should too.
                    <br />
                    As a Life Path 1, be careful and don't try to control everything and everyone around you as you plow headlong towards your goals. In life it is still beneficial to maintain a balance.
                    <br />
                    Confidence, creativity, and originality are very popular characteristics of a Life Path 1.
                </p>
            </div>
```

And this is the button to show it.

```
<input type="submit" value="calculate" onclick="calculator(); switchVisible(FinalLifeNumber);" style="background-color:cornflowerblue; object-position:100px;"/>
```

This is what I only see afterwards.

[image]

Comment: add `FinalLifeNumber()` to this post

Comment: I won't try to read all your code, its scope is quite confusing. But I'll try to help you, maybe this can show you a path to get your objective: https://jsfiddle.net/0ka3gouL/

Comment: Simple code is a good thing for asking questions. No apology necessary. :D

Answer (score 1):

So,

If `FinalLifeNumber` is a global, you can access it straight from `switchVisible()`.

Otherwise, you can add a parameter to `switchVisible()` like this:

```
switchVisible(LifeNumber) {
    // and use it like any other var as LifeNumber

}
```

When you call it, just call `switchVisible()` like this:

```
switchVisible(FinalLifeNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new too but i would suggest to make it a bit different. Make array  `lifeplan[1]` till `lifeplan[9]` with text you want to display for each number (including html tags like h1 style= ... etc.). Then in html make only one empty div element `id="lifeplan"` instead of hidding 9 of them. And in main function after you calculate that FinalLifeNumber from 1 till 9 do `document.getElementById("lifeplan").innerhtml=lifeplan[FinalLifeNumber]`
In case you don't like it...in function FinalLifeNumber() at end add `return result` ... where is your number...second way is declare variable FinalLifeNumber outside function at script beginning with `var` then it will be global and visible to all following functions.